# How can I define an SSIS For Loop Eval expression using int datatypes?

Tags: ssis

I am creating what should be a very simple evaluation expression
`@[User::varCount] == 0`
The variable is int32 and is using a script task to get a count.  If the count variable is 0, the loop ends. No matter how I have tried to write this, including type casts, I get "Cannot convert System.Boolean to System.String".
Both sides of the expression are integers, so what can I do to make SSIS understand it?

Answer (score 0):

You must have something "off" in the way you have your task set up as what you have provided works just fine. Given the error message about conversion from boolean to string, I'd check other places, like the InitExpression or if it's the Script Task that's actually throwing the error.

Given a package that looks something like this (For Loop Container with a Script Task inside)

[image]

@[User::varCount] is defined as an Int32 with an initial value of -1

I configured my FLC to be

[image]

- InitExpression: @[User::varCount = -2
- EvalExpression: @[User::varCount] == 0
- AssignExpression: *No value provided*

My script task is defined as

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ST_075f854410774a6793674ae516b9aca5
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            var fireAgain = false;

            foreach (var item in Dts.Variables)
            {
                Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Debug before", string.Format("{0}.{1} -> {2}", item.Namespace, item.Name, item.Value), "", 0, ref fireAgain);
            }

            // Lazy conversion of value to string here for evaluation instead of int    
            if (Dts.Variables["User::varCount"].Value.ToString() == "0")
            {
                Dts.Variables["User::varCount"].Value = -1;
            }

            foreach (var item in Dts.Variables)
            {
                Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Debug after", string.Format("{0}.{1} -> {2}", item.Namespace, item.Name, item.Value), "", 0, ref fireAgain);
            }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };

    }
}
```

Results

```
SSIS package "C:\Users\bfellows\source\repos\SO_Trash\SO_Trash\SO_68529686.dtsx" starting.
Information: 0x0 at Script Task, Debug before: User.varCount -> 0
Information: 0x0 at Script Task, Debug after: User.varCount -> -1
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  I found that my problem isn't really the problem after all.  When I enter the expressions directly in any of the For Loop expression fields, it works just fine. The datatype error was when I tried to use the Property Expressions Editor to build the expression.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know where you use this expression. But I try this in SSIS 2017 with the task is named "Expression Task". In this task I wrote your command with the same situation (My variable is int32 too) and it works well and I did not get any error for converting.
My Command that I used is this: "@[User::varCount] == 0".
after use this task, you can use its green output arrow to handle the rest of your package when result is true.